# Increase height of Container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to increase the height of the main body area on my hosted website i.e. the gradient to fill the space below the button as well.

Link - https://surijatin.github.io/covid-second-dose/

Github Repo - https://github.com/surijatin/covid-second-dose

I have tried adding the `height: 100vh` to the container but is there any better way as well? Doing this way adds a scroll bar and still leaves some white space below.

Comment: Please post the code here.

Comment: Would be very difficult for me to post the working example here in the code. Can you let me know what are you expecting off me when you say you need code?

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

**1. Remove body margin.**

So, change this...

```
body {
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    margin: 20px 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

...into this.

```
body {
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

**2. Add margin-top & margin-bottom and height to the `header-container`.**

So, change this...

```
.header-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

...into this.

```
.header-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 2vh 0 2vh 0;
    height: 2vh;
}
```

**3. Change padding unit and add height to the `main-container`.**

So, change this...

```
.main-container {
    background: linear-gradient(130deg,#3c91e7,#78378c);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2%;
}
```

...into this.

```
.main-container {
    background: linear-gradient(130deg,#3c91e7,#78378c);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2vh 2vh 2vh 2vh;
    height: calc(100vh - 10vh);
}
```

The trick here is to have all margins, paddings and heights in the same relative unit (i.e., `vh`). Why? Because then you can use `calc` to calculate the height of the `main-container` so that it fills the entire space left.

The calculation:

- margin from the `header-container`: 2vh (margin-top) + 2vh (margin-bottom) = 4vh,
- height from the `header-container`: 2vh and
- padding from the `main-container`: 2vh (padding-top) + 2vh (padding-bottom) = 4vh.

All together it's 10vh. If you subtract 10vh from 100vh, the `main-container` will fill the entire space left.

Comment: This solves my problem. Thanks for the deep explanation.Much appreciated. Didn't know that keeping hold of all these measurements was this easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox.

```css
.App {
    height: calc(100vh - 40px); /* account for top and bottom margin on body */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.main-container {
    flex-grow: 1; /* fill remaining space */
}
```